# css text animation on display none using keyframe is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been assigned a task by my professor to implement a notification when the user clicks the Copy Icon. I attempted to utilize `@keyframes` with opacity, but unfortunately, it didn't yield the desired outcome. I would appreciate your guidance on how to rectify this issue. Below are the relevant sections of my code.

Here's how I setup my keyframes.

```
.copyNotification {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }

  .copyNotification.show {
    display: block;
    animation: show 0.5s backwards;
  }

  @keyframes show {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(-100%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

```js
const copyBtn = document.querySelector("#copyBtn");
const copyNotification = document.querySelector("#copyNotification");


copyBtn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  copyNotification.classList.add("show");
});
```

```css
:root {
  /*  Font Size */
  --ff--primary: "Chivo", sans-serif;
  /* Font Weight */
  --fw--bold: 400;
  --fw--very-bold: 600;

  /* Colors */
  --clr--purple: hsl(250, 95%, 74%);
  --clr--white: hsl(0, 0%, 100%);
}

/*
  1. Use a more-intuitive box-sizing model.
*/
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
/*
    2. Remove default margin
  */
* {
  margin: 0;
}
/*
    Typographic tweaks!
    3. Add accessible line-height
    4. Improve text rendering
  */
body {
  line-height: 1.5;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/*
    5. Improve media defaults
  */
img,
picture,
video,
canvas,
svg {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}
/*
    6. Remove built-in form typography styles
  */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}
/*
    7. Avoid text overflows
  */
p,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
/*
    8. Create a root stacking context
  */
#root,
#__next {
  isolation: isolate;
}

body {
  background-color: var(--clr--purple);
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-family: var(--ff--primary);
  font-size: var(--fw--bold);
}

.passwordForm {
  display: grid;
  height: 200px;
  max-width: 450px;
  background-color: var(--clr--white);
  padding: 1.5rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;

  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .divider {
    border-top: 1.5px solid var(--clr--purple);
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-inline: -1.5rem;
  }

 
  form {
    display: grid;
    gap: 2rem;
    
     .copyNotification {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }

  .copyNotification.show {
    display: block;
    animation: show 0.5s backwards;
  }

  @keyframes show {
    0% {
      transform: translateY(0%);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
      transform: translateY(-100);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }


    .passwordDisplay {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;

      .copyBtn {
        position: absolute;
        font-size: 2rem;
        top: 0;
        right: 1rem;

        i {
          cursor: pointer;
          color: var(--clr--purple);
        }

        i:hover {
          opacity: 0.7;
        }

        i:active {
          opacity: 0.5;
        }
      }

      .passwordValue {
        border: 2px solid #937efc;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 0.7rem 1rem;
      }
      .passwordValue:focus {
        border-color: hsl(250, 95%, 74%, 0.6);
        -webkit-box-shadow: -2px 4px 15px -6px rgba(147, 126, 252, 1);
        -moz-box-shadow: -2px 4px 15px -6px rgba(147, 126, 252, 1);
        box-shadow: -2px 4px 15px -6px rgba(147, 126, 252, 1);
        outline: 0 none;
      }
    }

    }

  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" class="css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.2/css/all.min.css"
    />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Chivo:wght@400;600&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>Password Generator JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main class="passwordForm">
      <h1>Password Generator</h1>
      <div class="divider"></div>
      <form action="#">
        <div class="passwordDisplay">
          <input
            type="text"
            disabled="disabled"
            class="passwordValue"
            id="passwordValue"
            placeholder="Password"
          />
          <div class="copyBtn" id="copyBtn">
            <i class="fa-regular fa-copy"></i>
          </div>
          <p class="copyNotification" id="copyNotification">Copied</p>
        </div>

       
      </form>
    </main>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you give use the compiled CSS? Currently it's nested like SASS/SCSS

Comment: @disinfor I think CSS supports nesting (and so do the more popular browsers).

Comment: @AHaworth I haven't used straight CSS in so long. HA! Good to know that nesting is now a thing.

Comment: translateY(-100) - 100what (% or px or...)